# How to resize image in this PHP script?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I'm experimenting with php script via ajax which uploads an array of images from [this source.](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/)

While it works excellent I'm trying to enter php code which resizes images to 120px by width or height (whichever is larger). 
For my sanity please help how to update code:

```
$demo_mode = false;
$upload_dir = 'uploads/';
$allowed_ext = array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif');

if(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) != 'post'){
    exit_status('Error! Wrong HTTP method!');
}

if(array_key_exists('pic',$_FILES) && $_FILES['pic']['error'] == 0 ){

    $pic = $_FILES['pic'];

    if(!in_array(get_extension($pic['name']),$allowed_ext)){
        exit_status('Only '.implode(',',$allowed_ext).' files are allowed!');
    }   

    if($demo_mode){

        // File uploads are ignored. We only log them.

        $line = implode('       ', array( date('r'), $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $pic['size'], $pic['name']));
        file_put_contents('log.txt', $line.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

        exit_status('Uploads are ignored in demo mode.');
    }

    // Move the uploaded file from the temporary
    // directory to the uploads folder:

    if(move_uploaded_file($pic['tmp_name'], $upload_dir.$pic['name'])){
        exit_status('File was uploaded successfuly!');
    }

}

exit_status('Something went wrong with your upload!');

// Helper functions

function exit_status($str){
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>$str));
    exit;
}

function get_extension($file_name){
    $ext = explode('.', $file_name);
    $ext = array_pop($ext);
    return strtolower($ext);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I took an example of "promaty" from this [LINK](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php)  and call from loop:

```
<?php

$dir = "uploads/*.*";
$images = glob( $dir );

foreach( $images as $file ):
    $px = 120;
    $prefix = $px . "_";
    $dst = "uploads/" . $prefix . basename($file);
    $resized = image_resize($file, $dst, $px, $px);
    echo "<img src='" . $dst . "' />";
    echo "<p>" . basename($dst) . " </p>";
endforeach;
```

...and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can install [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) on your server:

```
<?php
function resize_image($file, $w, $h, $crop=FALSE) {
    $img = new Imagick($file);
    if ($crop) {
        $img->cropThumbnailImage($w, $h);
    } else {
        $img->thumbnailImage($w, $h, TRUE);
    }

    return $img;
}
resize_image(‘/path/to/some/image.jpg’, 150, 150);
```

Another way would be using the [PHP-GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php):

```
<?php
function resize_image($file, $w, $h, $crop=FALSE) {
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
    $r = $width / $height;
    if ($crop) {
        if ($width > $height) {
            $width = ceil($width-($width*($r-$w/$h)));
        } else {
            $height = ceil($height-($height*($r-$w/$h)));
        }
        $newwidth = $w;
        $newheight = $h;
    } else {
        if ($w/$h > $r) {
            $newwidth = $h*$r;
            $newheight = $h;
        } else {
            $newheight = $w/$r;
            $newwidth = $w;
        }
    }
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

    return $dst;
}

$img = resize_image(‘/path/to/some/image.jpg’, 150, 150);
```

Comment: Kuf, thanks, but you gave me function which I have to call from loop which collects all image files. ?please, see: if(array_key_exists('pic',$_FILES) && $_FILES['pic']['error'] == 0 ){
 $pic = $_FILES['pic'];
$pic=resize_image('uploads/', 150, 150);

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// The file
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$percent = 0.5;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new dimensions
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$new_width = $width * $percent;
$new_height = $height * $percent;

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
```

Find more at [php.net](http://php.net/imagecopyresampled)

Comment: I saw that tutorial, but couldn't include it in my script. Although, have problems with php iterations; in javascript I can do whatever I wont, but in PHP just can't figure.